# get a table completely moved to another table PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a 3 column table and on a submit button press I want to basically move the old table to a new table. As this is happening I want the old table being deleted as the submit button pressed and I only want the new entries in the table copied on the button press? Any insight on the best way I should go about this? I was previously trying a select into.

Comment: Why do you need to drop the table? Why can you not just delete rows from the table that are unneeded? Is it a giant table from which deletion takes a long time?

Comment: the table that the information is going to is going to be a searchable table. The table that the information is coming from is the table where incoming data is sent and we want the two tables to have separate and different functionality

Answer (score 0):

Different options, just two ways come to mind:

Assuming you enter the php page from the HTTP GET/POST.

If you have any foreign keys set:

1. Use a create stable with select (create your new table and insert
   the records)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

1. delete all record from the first table
2. insert new data

If you have no foreign keys set

1. rename first table

RENAME TABLE student TO student_new

1. create the new table
2. insert new data